# Axis break where one side has no data plotted? (near zero)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

**The issue**

I have a line plot with several variables where the data values are well above zero. This plot also has two separate y-axes corresponding respectively to the solid and dotted lines. I've noted the data values in the y-axis labels, but my mentor thinks I should also add an axis break just above zero to draw attention to the fact that these values are far above zero and to show that, say, solid CTRL is not twice the magnitude of solid MFKC.

I've looked up examples of axis breaks with matplotlib, but all of the ones I've seen involve data spanning both "sides" of the plot, with separate axes used for both halves. I don't have any data I want to plot below the break, and adding more axes to a plot that already has two might be needlessly complicated.

**The code**

```
#Plot
x= np.arange(0,3)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

#DOD
dod1 = ax.plot(x, ctrl_dod,  color='r',      label='CTRL'  )
dod2 = ax.plot(x, mfkc_dod,  color='orange', label='MFKC'  )
dod3 = ax.plot(x, gses_dod,  color='green',  label='GSES'  )
dod4 = ax.plot(x, gses3_dod, color='blue',   label='GSES-3')
dod5 = ax.plot(x, gses4_dod, color='purple', label='GSES-4')
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-')
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
ax.set_ylabel('Dust Optical Depth')
ax.legend()
ax.set_title('Global Mean DOD and DCM')

#DCM
ax2  = ax.twinx()
dcm1 = ax2.plot(x, ctrl_dcm*1e6,  color='r',       linestyle='--')
dcm2 = ax2.plot(x, mfkc_dcm*1e6,  color='#e68a00', linestyle='--')
dcm3 = ax2.plot(x, gses_dcm*1e6,  color='green',   linestyle='--')
dcm4 = ax2.plot(x, gses3_dcm*1e6, color='blue',    linestyle='--')
dcm5 = ax2.plot(x, gses4_dcm*1e6, color='purple',  linestyle='--')
ax2.yaxis.grid(True)
ax2.xaxis.grid(True)
ax2.set_xlabel('Month')
ax2.set_ylabel('Dust Column Mass (mg m-2)')
#Limits
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([-0.25,2.25])

#Labels
axes.set_xticks(x)
axes.set_xticklabels(['June','July','August'])

#Save
pylab.savefig('dod+dcm.png')
```

[image]

**The question**

If I change my y-axis ranges to both start at zero, how can I add a line break just above zero (and below 0.020 and 40) on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

Create a numpy array with all values of 0.020 and the same shape as the time array. Plot that array against time and turn on the dot connecting (i.e. draw trend line). You can do the same for 40. Then just set the lower y limit to zero.

Comment: I don't think I understand how this would work. Could you possibly provide a simple example, please?